# Changing terminal name in centos

Tags: terminal, centos, amazon-web-services

I am very new to this centos terminal and aws. I would like to ask you how to change the terminal name and replacing the default name with ec2user@ip. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Are we talking about the terminal prompt? If so, you're looking at the variable `PS1`. From bash, this can be changed by issuing for example `export PS1=\u@\h\$` (which is most likely similar to what you already have). Change the part after `=` to whatever you want.

Depending on what you want as your prompt, you need different variables in the export. Here's a list of the ones available:

```
 \d   The date, in "Weekday Month Date" format (e.g., "Tue May 26"). 
 \h   The hostname, up to the first . (e.g. deckard) 
 \H   The hostname. (e.g. deckard.SS64.com)
 \j   The number of jobs currently managed by the shell. 
 \l   The basename of the shell's terminal device name. 
 \s   The name of the shell, the basename of $0 (the portion following the final slash). 
 \t   The time, in 24-hour HH:MM:SS format. 
 \T   The time, in 12-hour HH:MM:SS format. 
 \@   The time, in 12-hour am/pm format. 
 \u   The username of the current user. 
 \v   The version of Bash (e.g., 2.00) 
 \V   The release of Bash, version + patchlevel (e.g., 2.00.0) 
 \w   The current working directory. 
 \W   The basename of $PWD. 
 \!   The history number of this command. 
 \#   The command number of this command. 
 \$   If you are not root, inserts a "$"; if you are root, you get a "#"  (root uid = 0) 
 \nnn   The character whose ASCII code is the octal value nnn. 
 \n   A newline. 
 \r   A carriage return. 
 \e   An escape character (typically a color code). 
 \a   A bell character.
 \\   A backslash. 
 \[   Begin a sequence of non-printing characters. (like color escape sequences). This
      allows bash to calculate word wrapping correctly.
 \]   End a sequence of non-printing characters.
```

Experiment with various values in PS1, and once you've found a set that you like, you can stick the command into `~/.bashrc` to make the change permanent.